# nativescript application runs slow and freezes when navigating on android devices but runs excellent on ios

Tags: nativescript

I have exhausted any suggestions available online.
I have tried setting markingMode in the package.json

> ```
> "android": {
>     "markingMode": "none"
> }
> ```

I have tried several methods of loading the viewModels.
I have tried saving to physical files and reading from them.
I have tried loading the json data fore each view into the appSettings.

I have tried uninstalling sass plugin sidedrawer plugin.
I have updated all the plugins including the core components.

Here are the plugins/versions

```
  nativescript-appversion          │ ^1.4.1  │ │
  nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager   │ ^1.4.0  │ │
  nativescript-keyboard-toolbar    │ ^1.0.4  │ │
  nativescript-local-notifications │ ^3.1.0  │ │
  nativescript-orientation         │ ^2.2.1  │ │ 
  nativescript-pager               │ ^9.3.14 │ │ 
  nativescript-plugin-firebase     │ ^8.0.0  │ │
  nativescript-pulltorefresh       │ ^2.2.0  │ │
  nativescript-social-share        │ ^1.5.1  │ │ 
  nativescript-sound               │ ^1.0.4  │ │ 
  nativescript-ui-sidedrawer       │ ^6.0.0  │ │
  nativescript-windowed-modal      │ ^5.0.6  │ │ 
  rxjs                             │ ^6.3.3  │ │ 
  tns-core-modules                 │ ^5.2.2
```

The application should be able to navigate different views without freezing or slowing down.

Comment: There must be some memory leak, did you try inspecting with timeline view, see where exactly it is taking time?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the history? https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation#router-link

Comment: I have tried clearing the history on navigating and it still freezes up intermittently.
I will try to look for memory leaks.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior in NS 6 + Angular on Android. Runs fine on iOS.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing exact the same issue. Use the configuration below on `/src/package.json`, not in the main package.json.

```
{
  "main": "main.js",
  "android": {
    "v8Flags": "--expose_gc",
    "markingMode": "none"
  }
}
```

More info here: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/markingmode-none-is-official-boost-android-performance-while-avoiding-memory-issues